# JavaFX 8 - Weird ParallelCamera behavior for ImageViews

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

I want to create a small game with JavaFX 8. It's based on 'Asteroids', for those that don't know:
Asteroids spawn from all sides of your window/screen and you have to shoot them with a spaceship which can freely move within the screen borders.

I ran into a problem though. To delete an asteroid from the screen when it passes outside I check if they are outside the screen borders (x and y coords: 600x480).
But now I can't let them spawn outside to avoid them appearing instant on screen.

So I thought about using a ParallelCamera and move it to x = 100 and y = 100 to create a 100px wide zone where I can spawn asteroids and send them to the other side of the screen.

When I implement the camera, images only appear after I resize the whole window manually or update camera translations. Without the camera set to a specific location everything works as intended. My goal is ofc to get the images on screen without having to resize the whole window...

The weird thing is that a rectangle is shown correctly, but an ImageView is not.

I can't post images yet so I have to describe them:
1.No ParallelCamera/ParallelCamera without modified translations (x/y coords):
Everything works as intended. A green rectangle and a small 18x18 image   representing a player.
2. ParallelCamera's X and Y have been set to 100:
Green rectangle can still be seen but no player image. After manually resizing the window or changing ParallelCamera's X and Y again the image appears on screen on its intended location.

I tried everything I can imagine and almost 400 people visited a forum thread about it (no answer so far).

The code:
http://pastebin.java-gaming.org/8d79c3d193319

Comment: For images visit: http://www.java-gaming.org/index.php/topic,36459.msg346006.html#msg346006

Answer (score 0):

Ok, after several hours I found a solution:
Moving/translating the ParallelCamera with camera.setTranslateX, camera.relocate(var1, var2) seem to break something, since images get cut off by the amount of pixels you translate the camera when you e.g. use a small number in setTranslateX().

Further it seems like i don't have to use a ParallelCamera at all, I can spawn those asteroids on negative x and y coords and let them fly around.

Then the best thing at the end:
Using setLayoutX/Y (and possibly setTranslateX/Y) on your scene graph's root node (in my case a Group node) achieves almost the result I wanted to have with camera.setTranslateX/Y. 
The difference between those two is the following:
root.setLayoutX(100) moves every x coordinate 100 units to the right by adding 100 to all nodes whereas camera.setTranslateX(100) moves the eye 100 units to the right without changing the coordinates.

TL;DR: I didn't know that I could set negative coords which solves my problem. Well I learnt a lot today...about coordinates.